# How to hide an ASP.NET menu item?

Tags: asp.net

This question was asked before but what I need is to simply hide a menu Item rather than remove it . I was surprised to see that ASp.NET MenuItem has no Visible property. is there any way really yo hide a menu Item

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide the menu item using css. just use CssClass property. [Using CSS and Styles with the Menu Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately menuItem does not seem to have CssClass Either

Comment: please see the link carefully. it has the detail how to do that.for more information try followings.[StaticMenuItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticmenuitemstyle.aspx),
[DynamicMenuItemStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamicmenuitemstyle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and my work around was actually having two separate menus. I assigned my Admin controls that i wanted to hide in its own menu. I positioned them next to eachother as if they are one and i hide the menu when the user doesn't have access in my codebehind.